# MySQL Workbench Error: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, mysql-workbench

I am trying to connect Wordpress database into my MySQL Workbench app. when i provide SFTP details in connection settings i've got Error.

'Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0'

Kindly please advise

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This message appears usually when the reply from the remote end doesn't match the MySQL protocol expected by the client side., which often means the other end is no MySQL server at all.